# How to handle file path in Perl?

Tags: perl, filepath

I've the following script which is  used to read files in the given path!in this script let's assume path like

```
chdir("/usr/test1/street/accounts/goal/routecab/Prpbict")
```

work nicely but

```
chdir("/usr/test1/street/accounts/goal/routecab/EventDir")
```

The directory didn't change! Can anybody tell me the reason!

**run time**

```
dir_name=Event\ Based\Mailers_Registration_Welcome.htm
```

after append the dir_name into working dir it seems:`$main_dir=/usr/test1/site/accounts/coach/rulecab/Event\ Based\ Mailers_Registration_Welcome.htm`
after run:-`chdir($main_dir);print`pwd`;`it will print this this alone what about remaining path i mean dir_name /usr/test1/site/accounts/coach/rulecab

Comment: Can you prove that the path is correct? Add output in your post of a `$ ls /usr/test1/street/accounts/goal/routecab/EventDir` from your terminal

Comment: ya i can find this dir manually!

Comment: see i'm running this script in for loop!!!when ever a dire starts with E come it 'll skip  the remaining path in the about case dir changed only  /usr/test1/street/accounts/goal/routecab/ this path alone

Comment: @ThiyaguATR Well, for one thing, that statement `chdir(/usr/....)` would give you some rather verbose error messages, mainly having to do with you not quoting the string. Don't submit code that doesn't even compile when asking questions.

Comment: actually here 'm using variable man!ex:-my $path='/usr/test1/street/accounts/goal/routecab/EventDir'; chdir $path or die "Unable to chdir: $!";

Comment: @TLP see it did't give any error message at all!it simple ignore the remaining path!

Comment: How do you know it doesn't chdir?

Comment: after and before chdir i'm printing pwd 'm getting same path for directory strat with e if not it work fine

Comment: Your latest edit seems to imply that the path you have said you used is not the one you did use. So perhaps you should clarify that by posting code that shows *exactly* what you did.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28829/discussion-between-thiyagu-atr-and-tlp)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have quotes around your path?

To find why `chdir` is failing you should write

```
chdir '/usr/test1/street/accounts/goal/routecab/EventDir'
        or die "Unable to chdir: $!";
```

and perl will tell you the reason.

Comment: actually here 'm using variable man!ex:-my $path='/usr/test1/street/accounts/goal/routecab/EventDir';
        chdir $path or die "Unable to chdir: $!";

Comment: @Thiyagu ATR: And is it reporting something? Is is exit there or continue to work?